# How get key of second Dictionary placed in first Dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I need get k2 value from dt. How can i do it?

```
Set dt = New Dictionary
Set dt2 = New Dictionary
k1 = A
k2 = B
s = C
dt2.Add k2, s
dt.Add k1, dt2
```

Comment: First of all, use Option Explicit and Dim all your variables

Comment: Possibly `dt.Item(k1).Item(k2)`.

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Storax it is return s value

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld i need something like this dt.item(k1).Key(k2).Name (not item(k2) value)

Comment: Please have a look at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/key-property). `Key` is a property where you can change the key but you cannot retrieve anything. Please edit your post accordingly in order to clarify what your issue is. [This](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) is also a good tutorial to get known to the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to return a list of the keys of each dictionary (dt2) that is stored in another dictionary (dt).

Understanding that each dictionary might have multiple keys, you need to construct a nested loop.

eg:

```
Sub due()
    Dim dt As Dictionary, dt2 As Dictionary
    Dim k1, k2, s
    
k1 = "A"
k2 = "B"
s = "C"

Set dt = New Dictionary
Set dt2 = New Dictionary

dt2.Add k2, s
dt.Add k1, dt2

Dim ka, kb
    For Each ka In dt.Keys
        For Each kb In dt(ka).Keys
            Debug.Print kb
        Next kb
    Next ka
End Sub
```

Will return the keys of all the nested dictionaries stored in each dictionary item of the outer dictionary